# Expectation of kth order statistic of Pareto distribution

Tags: self-study, expected-value, order-statistics, pareto-distribution

I am trying to find the expected value of $X_{(k)}$ 
Given cdf $$ F(x) = \begin{cases}
1-\left(\frac{\sigma}{x}\right)^\alpha, & x > \sigma\\ 
0, & \text{else.} \end{cases}$$

My attempt:
$$f_{X_{(k)}}(x)=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}f_X(x)[F_{X}(x)]^{k-1}[1-F_X(x)]^{n-k}$$

$$E(X_{(k)})=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\alpha \sigma^{\alpha(n-k+1)}\int_\sigma^\infty [x^{\alpha}-\sigma^{\alpha}]^{k-1}[x]^{-n\alpha}dx$$

I cannot simplify the integral further.

Comment: Substitute $x^\alpha=\sigma^\alpha/y$, simplify, and compare to the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).